# TypeError when trying to upload a fine-tuned T5 model to Hugging Face Model Hub using push_to_hub

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

Hi following [tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/t5_hf_summarization/), I created a fine-tuned version of t5 model using Keras API, and inferencing works well.

But I’m having a some problem with uploading the model to the hub

As written in the tutorial, I tried pushing the model using following code:

```
model.push_to_hub("textSummary", organization="organName")
```

But this gave me this error saying 'TypeError: HfApi.create_repo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization'

So I tried 3 other following methods, but all those line giving me same error:

```
# method 1
model.push_to_hub('textSummary')
# method 2
model.push_to_hub('Seungjun/textSummary')
# method 3
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login, create_repo
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
create_repo("Seungjun/textSummary", private=False)
model.push_to_hub('Seungjun/textSummary')
```

Can I get some any help please